# how to get Orientation.lock status in react native

Tags: react-native, settings, react-native-ios

I have a react native demo project. I need to determine whether the ios Orientation settings are locked, and determine whether to rotate according to the system settings on a certain page.
for example ,I can get status with `Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION` in android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqa0k.jpg)

I hope someone can help me,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works with both ios and android. When your device orientation has changed, only then this action will trigger, so that you can determine to rotate the page.

```
_orientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE') {
  // do something with landscape layout
} else {
  // do something with portrait layout
}
```

}

[react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer I want。